# Crash when Kill/Close thread in android

Tags: android, multithreading, audio-recording, audiotrack

I am making a program to record and play audio. It works well. However, the problem is that the program is crash when I press back button (right bottom). Let see my clean code and please help me to fix it. Thanks in advance

```
  private void cleanUp()
  {
    if (track != null)
    {
      mVisualizerView.release();
      track.release();
      track = null;
    }
    if (mWakeLock.isHeld()) { 
        mWakeLock.release();
    }
    if(mIsRecording)
    {       
    mRecorder.stop();
    try {
        //Write file audio
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    /////////////////Stop audio service
     _audioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
    }
    mRecorder.release();
  }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    cleanUp();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    cleanUp();     
    super.onPause();
}
```

In which, these variables are constructed/used as bellow code

```
private boolean mIsRecording = false;
AudioTrack track =null;
private AudioManager _audioManager;
private VisualizerView mVisualizerView;
protected PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
private AudioRecord mRecorder;

// Prevent phone from sleeping
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
this.mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag"); 
this.mWakeLock.acquire();
//Record audio
private void startBufferedWrite(final File file) {  
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            DataOutputStream output = null;
            try {
                    output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));
                    ///////////Play during recording
                    track.play();                  
                    mVisualizerView = (VisualizerView) findViewById(R.id.visualizerView);
                    mVisualizerView.link(track);
                    while (mIsRecording) {
                    //Write to track
                    }
                }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

The error is that

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-35897
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: what you want to do with UI(VisualizerView) in thread.

Comment: VisualizerView is one class to display visualization of music. The code is reference from https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer

Comment: but how can you access the UI from background thread??

Comment: I think thats the problem of crash.

Comment: try to use `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            btn.setText("#" + i);
                        }
                    });` inside your run method.

Comment: You are right. I moved mVisualizerView = (VisualizerView) findViewById(R.id.visualizerView); on to onCreate(). It look fine. Thank you so much. However, Do you see my clear function. Is it ok? I did not close the thread

Comment: it seems ok.. but use try catch block... i suggest :)
I am posting my answer.. plz accept it

Comment: Please add try catch in there. And if it is possible, Please close my thread in onDestroy as well as onPause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to use UI elements in non-UI thread.That is the cause of crash.

you can try something like this.

```
new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            DataOutputStream output = null;
        try {
                output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));
                ///////////Play during recording
                track.play();  
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                      mVisualizerView =(VisualizerView) findViewById(R.id.visualizerView);
                     mVisualizerView.link(track);
                     while (mIsRecording) {
                       //Write to track
                       }
                      }
                    });

        }
    }.start();
```